# Radiant CMS and MySQL

Tags: ruby, ubuntu-12.04, radiant

I'm trying to install Radiant CMS, but I having a problem trying to configure it with MySQL...

I follow the next tut , to install Radiant

https://github.com/radiant/radiant/wiki/Installing-on-Ubuntu

and then in the last step:

```
    rake db:bootstrap
NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem.source_index called from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rails-2.3.18/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:21.
rake aborted!
**adapter:mysql database:dev_earth0 username:root password:dbpass host:localhost database is not configured**
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-2.3.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:62:in `establish_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-2.3.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:60:in `establish_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-2.3.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:55:in `establish_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rails-2.3.18/lib/initializer.rb:438:in `initialize_database'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rails-2.3.18/lib/initializer.rb:141:in `process'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rails-2.3.18/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/radiant-1.1.3/lib/radiant/initializer.rb:266:in `run'
/home/devdreams/domains/dreamsengineering.com/config/environment.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `block in require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:547:in `new_constants_in'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rails-2.3.18/lib/tasks/misc.rake:4:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:203:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:203:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:183:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:203:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:203:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:183:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:bootstrap => db:initialize => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I'm always getting that the db wasn't created... :(

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](https://github.com/peritor/webistrano/issues/34), they have an advice which might be useful for you.

```
gem update --system 1.6.2
```